# Data coming from Controller in JSON format not binding to Grid

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, jqgrid

I have a controller, which returns list of objects in **JSONResult** format. In my view, I have written **$.ajax** method to get the data from the controller. I'm using **Knockout JS** for data-binding to my grid. Data is binding to the grid when I hard-code the values (the code block below which is commented). But when I pass the data from an ajax call it is not binding. Can anybody please help me to fix this?

The Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FetchMyData()
{
    List<SomeData> myData = new List<SomeData>();
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.myData = new List<SomeData>();

    model.myData.Add(new SomeData() { Id = 1, Record = "Record 1", RecType = "Type 1" });
    model.myData.Add(new SomeData() { Id = 2, Record = "Record 2", RecType = "Type 2" });
    model.myData.Add(new SomeData() { Id = 3, Record = "Record 3", RecType = "Type 3" });
    model.myData.Add(new SomeData() { Id = 4, Record = "Record 4", RecType = "Type 4" });
    model.myData.Add(new SomeData() { Id = 5, Record = "Record 5", RecType = "Type 5" });
    JsonResult outputResult = Json(model.myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return outputResult;
}
```

The ViewModel Code:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<SomeData> myData;
}

public class SomeData
{
    public int Id;
    public string Record;
    public string RecType;
}
```

The View Code:

```
<div data-bind="jqGrid:grid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonData;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '@Url.Action("FetchMyData", "Grid")',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (Data) {
            jsonData = Data;
        }
    });

    var model = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray(jsonData);

        //self.items = ko.observableArray([
        //    { "Id": 1, Record: "Record 1", Record Type: "Type 1" },
        //    { "Id": 2, Record: "Record 2", Record Type: "Type 2" },
        //    { "Id": 3, Record: "Record 3", Record Type: "Type 3" }
        //]);

        self.grid = new ko.jqGrid({
            dataSource: self.items,
            columns: [
                { type: "index", dataField: "Id" },
                { headerText: "Id", dataField: "Id" },
                { headerText: "Record", dataField: "Record" },
                { headerText: "Record Type", dataField: "Record Type" }
            ],
            allowSorting: true,
        });
    };
    var myModel = new model();
    ko.applyBindings(myModel);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are traing to use `jsonData` before data will be loaded from server.

Comment: The code which you posted have no relation to [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). Probably you use another grid?

Comment: @Oleg, you're right. Its not **jqGrid**. I can't mention the name of  the actual grid here. We have our own grid and that's internal to our project which I can't disclose here. So for time being I used jqGrid.

Comment: @Alexander when I run the code in debug mode, the `jsonData` is having the data as below:

`{ "Id": 1, Record: "Record 1", Record Type: "Type 1" },
  { "Id": 2, Record: "Record 2", Record Type: "Type 2" },
  { "Id": 3, Record: "Record 3", Record Type: "Type 3" }`

    Even though, it is not binding to the **Grid**.

Comment: @Kash I have a string feeling that if you place the following code on the line after `self.items = ...`, you'll see that the `jsonData` which you use to create the observable array is undefined: `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2));`. Your problem is that you never place the jsonData into the `items` observable array, which is why it works with the hard coded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy replacing your success function with this:

```
success: function (Data) {
    jsonData = Data;
    myModel.items(jsonData);
}
```